# Python daemon shows no output for an error

Tags: python, daemon, python-daemon

I read [How do you create a daemon in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473620/how-do-you-create-a-daemon-in-python) and also [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790876), and tried to write a very simple daemon :

```
import daemon
import time
with daemon.DaemonContext():
    while True:
        with open('a.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write('Hi')
        time.sleep(2)
```

Doing `python script.py` works and returns immediately to terminal (that's the expected behaviour). But `a.txt` is never written and I don't get any error message. **What's wrong with this simple `daemon`?**

Answer (score 2):

`daemon.DaemonContext()` has option `working_directory` that has default fault value `/` i.e. your program probably doesn't have permission to create a new file there.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's wrong with it, is it has no way to tell you what's wrong with it :-)

A daemon process is, by definition, detached from the parent process and from any controlling terminal. So if it's got something to say – such as error messages – it will need to arrange that before becoming a daemon.

From [the `python-daemon` FAQ document](https://alioth.debian.org/scm/loggerhead/python-daemon/trunk/view/head:/doc/FAQ):

> ### Why does the output stop after opening the daemon context?
>
> The specified behaviour in `PEP 3143`_ includes the requirement to
>   detach the process from the controlling terminal (to allow the process
>   to continue to run as a daemon), and to close all file descriptors not
>   known to be safe once detached (to ensure any files that continue to
>   be used are under the control of the daemon process).
>
> If you want the process to generate output via the system streams
>   ‘sys.stdout’ and ‘sys.stderr’, set the ‘DaemonContext’'s ‘stdout’
>   and/or ‘stderr’ options to a file-like object (e.g. the ‘stream’
>   attribute of a ‘logging.Handler’ instance). If these objects have file
>   descriptors, they will be preserved when the daemon context opens.

Set up a working channel of communication, such as a log file. Ensure the files you open aren't closed along with everything else, using the `files_preserve` option. Then log any errors to that channel.

Answer (score -1):

The problem described here is solved by J.J. Hakala's answer.

Two additional (important) things :

- [Sander's code](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/) (mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/473702/1422096)) is **better** than `python-daemon`. It is more reliable. Just one example: try to start *two times* the same daemon with `python-daemon` : big ugly error. With Sander's code : a nice notice "Daemon already running."
- For those who want to use `python-daemon` anyway: `DaemonContext()` only makes a daemon. `DaemonRunner()` makes a daemon + control tool, allowing to do `python script.py start` or `stop`, etc.